# How to change background color of android default alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a default alert dialog with listview of Text & Radio buttons.

I need to replace the image instead of text (Replace images instead of Facebook credit,paypal,Credit card shown below) & also needs to change alert dialog's background color.

I put style.xml file inside values folder also.

How could I implement that file in below code for changing background color?

My code:

```
 final CharSequence[] items = {"Facebook credit", "Paypal", "Credit Card"};

            //ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.AboutDialog );
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(paymentPage.this);
            builder.setTitle("Payment Gateway");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.gate);
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            payPalPayment();
                        }


                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Toast.makeText(paymentPage.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

My image:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you [create a custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).

Answer (score 1):

You should Customize AlertDialog Theme. Look at following post.

https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/customize-alertdialog-theme

This library might help you : https://github.com/avast/android-styled-dialogs

Answer (score 0):

I kinda faced the same problem. And the only way to solve it was extending my own version of layout. I see that in your case it is an AlertDialog. What I recommend you to do, is to create a unique class, that is your customized AlertDialog and create a layout for this, and then you inflate this.

[Here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example) is a post that helped me a lot.

I followed this post and solved my problem with customizing dialogs.

Please, if you have more doubts, let me know.

Thanks.